# Dinamically adjust UICollectonViewCell size according to its content while user is typing in UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to let the user edit some UITextViews inside a vertical UICollectionView.

Each UICollectionViewCell contains a single UITextView which has some random text (it can be one or many lines) and is editable.

When the user edit a UITextView, it's size change dynamically along with the content. Too bad the UICollectionViewCell itself instead keeps fixed size. 
I'm using the textViewDidChange method to resize dynamically the UITextView.

Is there a similar way to keep track of the changing content inside my CollectionViewCell and resize it properly?

Thanks